# Copy To Clipboard Function With Javascript

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript and I'm trying to have a button copy some text in the code to the clipboard. This doesn't seem to work.. Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = "myText";
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it wasnt working is because you cant do to a varaible `.select()` so when you do a   `document.execCommand("copy")` your copying any other selected text
try putting the stuff in a input box and then try `.select()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="myId" value="myText"> </input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myId");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and if you want to hide the textbox do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="myId" value="myText" style="display:none;"> </input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myId");
  copyText.style = "display:inline";
  copyText.select();
  copyText.style = "display:none";
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second one is what I was looking for. Thought I figured it out but it doesn't work unless the input box is showing...

Comment: can you  press the check mark so it looks like the question is solved please? if you do stackoverflow gives 10 good boy points.